# Validate a field's value if greater than another field's value in jQuery

Tags: validation, for-loop, if-statement

I am a begginer in jQuery could you help me build a script for this?

I have set's of fieldset which have set of input

```
<p><input type="radio" class="scenarioRadio" value="5" name="group26" /><label>Strongly agree </label></p>
<p><input type="radio" class="scenarioRadio" value="4" name="group26" /><label>Somewhat agree </label></p>
<p><input type="radio" class="scenarioRadio" value="3" name="group26" /><label>Neither agree or disagree</label></p>
<p><input type="radio" class="scenarioRadio" value="2" name="group26" /><label>Somewhat disagree</label></p>
<p><input type="radio" class="scenarioRadio" value="1" name="group26" /><label>Strongly disagree </label></p>
<p><input type="radio" class="scenarioRadio" value="0" name="group26" /><label>Don’t know / Can’t say</label>
```

Now I have set of conditions:

1. If two responses have equal numbers and they are next to each other, display the lower value response.

Ex.

**1st user answer:** Strongly agree [value="5"]
**2nd user answer:** Somewhat agree [value="4"] 
Final answer should be the lower rank: **Somewhat agree [value="4"]**

2. If two responses have equal numbers but are not next to each other, display "Don't know / Can't say"

Ex.

**4 say** they “Strongly disagree”
while **4 say** they “Somewhat agree” (which is what I mean by "equal numbers") 
Then the result is the lowest “Don’t know / Can’t say” [value="0"]

What should I use for this kind of conditions? and how to build it?

Thanks in advance!